How to control Randomness of a Voronoi texture in Texture Properties?
I was attempting to generate a grid of circles and import it into the compositor in Blender 4.3. Since it’s not possible to directly insert texture nodes into the compositor tab, I used the Texture node from Input > Texture. This allowed me to add procedural textures to the Compositor.
However, I noticed an issue: the Texture Properties panel lacks a slider for Randomness, which limits the customization options for procedural textures.

